# criação de triggers em mysql

Tags: banco-de-dados

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer uma triggers para mysql onde por ex uma pessoa entra para entregar um produto na empresa, na tabela movivisitaservico essa tabela é de movimentação de entrada de pessoas o tempo que cada umas dessa especialidade de entrega pode ficar é definido na tabela de especialidade, no movimento quando entro com a datae (data de entrada) e Horae (hora de entrada) teria que verificar o tempo que o entregador esta dentro da empresa para emitir um alerta para que fosse feita uma ligação para a pessoa que esta recebendo esse visitante que o tempo dele ja havia sido expirado ex datae = 13/10/2016, horae = 23:45 min, na tabela de especialidade esta defininido que esse entregado só pode ficar 40 min dentro da empresa isso quer dizer que quando fosse 00:25 caso essa pessoa não tivesse saido devo receber uma alerta que estourou o tempo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]